# Printing Average Score for Unique ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, aggregate-functions

I have a table

```
id | playerID | score
1  |    1     | 100
2  |    1     | 155
3  |    5     | 132
```

etc..

What I want to do is get the Average 'score' for each unique playerID. I can get the DISTINCT playerIDs

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    playerID
FROM
    dbo.scores
```

and I can get the average of all scores,

```
SELECT
    AVG(score)
FROM
    dbo.scores
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`!

```
SELECT playerID, AVG(score) AS avg_score
FROM dbo.scores
GROUP BY playerID
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `dbo` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  SQL Server does an *integer* average of integer values, so the average of `0` and `1` is `0`, not `0.5`.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT s.playerID, AVG(10. * s.score) AS avg_score
FROM dbo.scores s
GROUP BY s.playerID
```